# Numerical Analysis - Simple Newton-raphson method.

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

Question: $\tan(x)+\ln(x)$. Find a positive root of the equation with the Newton-Raphson method in 4 decimals.

This is a simple question about the Newton-Raphson method but I couldn't solve it. Would you help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: How far did you get in the solution? For example, perhaps you managed to calculate the derivative of the function?

Comment: yes I made the derivative of the function

Comment: What is then the problem ? The start value ? The iteration ?

Comment: Initial value and recurrence value are not specified in the question

Comment: Well, judging by the graph, the equation $f(x)=0$ has infinitely many solutions. Perhaps you just have to use your imagination and find one of them. You could start at, I dunno ... $x=1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the zero'**s** of function
$$f(x)=\tan(x)+\log(x)$$ This function is not very convenient because of the vertical asymptotes. So, it is better to consider
$$g(x)=\sin(x)+\log(x) \cos(x)$$ and search for the solutions of this one.

If you had a look at the plot, you probably noticed that the solutions are closer and closer to $(2k+1)\frac \pi 2$. To get an *estimate* of the solution (it will become the $x_0$ for Newton method), build a Taylor expansion
$$g(x)=1- \log 
   \left((2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\left(x-(2 k+1)\frac{\pi}{2} \right)+\cdots$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, the *estimate* of the $k^{th}$ root is then given by
$$x_0^{(k)}=(2 k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{\log 
   \left((2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$$

Except for the  first and second roots, it seems to be quite good
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 3 & 5.35747 &  5.25481 \\
 4 & 8.33918 &  8.29551 \\
 5 & 11.4127 &  11.3856 \\
 6 & 14.5147 &  14.4951 \\
 7 & 17.6297 &  17.6142 \\
 8 & 20.7519 &  20.7389
\end{array}
\right)$$